# Issue with sending array to action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I want to send array to my action method:

```
var items = { 'myIdList[]': [] };

        $(':checkbox').change(function () {            
            $(":checked").each(function () {
                items['myIdList[]'].push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#locationsCheckList').submit();
        });

        $('#locationsCheckList').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                traditional: true,
                data: { "myIdList": items }...
```

Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void GetLocations(int[] myIdList)...
```

items variable have data but when I pass it like this I get null but if I change

```
data: { "myIdList": items }
```

with

```
data: { "myIdList": [1,2,3,4,5] }
```

it works.
When I debug in browser in items variable I have values:

```
0: "1"
1: "2"
2: "3"
```

I can't pass array and I don't know why, if it works hardcoded?

Comment: do you use fiddler2?  Its really good for these situations, you will see exactly the difference between those two situations.  Not to mention it makes ajax programming a whole lot easier...  http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use a simple array, similar to your example that works:

```
var items = [];
// your jQuery loop
items.push($(this).val());
// and so on
data: { "myIdList": items }...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call needs to include:

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug, open the NET tab. You can see the details of your request (see if your data is there) as well as the response.

Comment: Now I see wired thing. In firebug I see that 'items' has values (item 0 value 5 etc.) but I have tried to call 'items.length' and I get undefined???